# jQuery Mobile form elements trigger('create')

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a form which AJAX loads two drop menus for state and country when a user inputs their zip code.

When the content is loaded jQuery("#element").trigger('create') is called.

All inputs are within a table, however when the above is called on the new elements, the width of ALL form inputs is changed to the full width of the screen rather than their containing td elements - pushing out the right hand side of the screen

How can I trigger the JQM styling on these new elements without them becoming the full width of the screen?

Comment: Add relevant code as well as JQM version.

Comment: The relevant code its right there: jQuery("#element").trigger('create') - jQuery Mobile 1.4.3

Comment: jQuery("#element").enhanceWithin() behaves exactly the same - does not "enhance within", but rather recreates the element without respect to the element it is within!

Comment: `.trigger("create")` is deprecated and replace with `.enhanceWithin()`, anyway, you will need to maniuplate `.ui-select` styles.

Comment: "you will need to maniuplate .ui-select styles" - ridiculous!

Comment: what's exactly ridiculous?

Comment: You have difficulty reading.  Twice now you have asked for what is already there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62850/discussion-between-omar-and-billy).